# How do I tell the YouTube app to play a certain resolution by default?

Tags: applications, youtube

I have capped internet and it gets very quickly consumed when YouTube keeps playing videos in 1080p by default. How do I set it to play all videos in 480p only?

Comment: On mobile devices, adjust quality settings by tapping Menu(3-dots vertical), then Quality/Settings icon .  Here you can choose what Quality you need. The video player will remember this for future playbacks.You can read more info [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/91449?hl=en-GB)

Comment: I did change it but it goes back to 1080p after some time and by the time I notice it, it has already done the damage.